# passing parameters in url

Tags: http, spring-mvc, get, parameter-passing

We currently have our site URL as:

http://www.domainname.com/en/def/filterSearch.html?level1=ghi&level3=GP&from=xyz

And want to make it SEO friendly in this form

http://www.domainname.com/en/def/filterSearch.html?ghi/GP

i.e., it passes a level1 and level3 parameter without equating it.  The level1 and level3 parameters are used in the controller to fetch profile data.  How can we remove special characters to make this URL SEO friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried path variables?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filterSearch.html/{level1}/{level3}") 
public final Object filterSearch(@PathVariable("level1")String level1, @PathVariable("level3"), String level3)
```

Comment: Hi Rob, so my <a href> in jsp is like <a href="filterSearch.html?level1=Health&level3=${healthCategory.categorySolr}&from=browseDirectory"> so can I use, <a href="filterSearch.html/Health/xyz"> when I use path variable?

Comment: yes. Have a look at 15.3.2 Mapping requests with @RequestMapping of the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html) for a better explanation.